# Node.js server crashing with TLS error

Tags: node.js

After about 30 minutes running an application that I created using an angular yeoman generator, I receive this breaking error:

```
tls.js:182
      var commonNames = cert.subject.CN;
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'CN' of undefined
    at Object.checkServerIdentity (tls.js:182:37)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1016:29)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:566:8)
```

I've been reading a bit and it seems that perhaps this is fixed in the latest version of NodeJS, but in the meantime does anyone know what is causing this error to occur?

Comment: Does the server's certificate has a valid subject name?

Comment: I haven't set up a certificate for the server. I think that there is some stock one that comes with the generator but I can't necessarily see it at the moment. Is a malformed certificate causing it to blow up?

Comment: It looks like that only. How can I reproduce this problem? Which command did you run?

Comment: Booting up the server using `grunt serve`. It seems to run between 10-30 minutes before crashing.

Comment: I should note too that this error only occurs on my server, and not when I am running the app locally. It looks though that there is a conditional check for this in the newest version of Node which I've just upgraded to: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/9272